# Regex to match domain name in string

Tags: php, regex

I've been searching about this and none of the proposed solutions I found have worked.

I'm looking for a regex expression to match domain names (and not subdomains) ending with a small set of TLDs (.com, .net, .me, .co) contained within other string, delimited by space.

---

**Examples:**

```
"Something | `Google.com`"

"Youtube.com/username FooBar"

"`Youtube.com` username"

"[123] Potato < `Example.net` >"

"sub.domain.com `domain.com`"

"~Username~ Domain.fr"

"~Username~ `Domain.co` Foo"
```

Comment: `\w+\.\w+` .................

Comment: \w+\.(com|net|me|co)\b  https://regex101.com/r/gP8gV2/1

Comment: \w+\.(com|edu|fr|co|net|org)

Answer (score 0):

`\w+\.(com|net|me|co)\b` [regex101.com/r/gP8gV2/1](https://regex101.com/r/gP8gV2/1) – splash58